# use angular-ui-router with bootstrap $modal to create a multi-step wizard

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router

The [FAQ for ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) has a section about integration with bootstrap $modals, but it doesn't mention anything about abstract views. I have 3 views under a single abstract view, so something like the following.

```
 $stateProvider
   .state('setup', {
     url: '/setup',
     templateUrl: 'initialSetup.html',
     controller: 'InitialSetupCtrl',
     'abstract': true
   })  

   // markup for the static view is
   <div class="wizard">
     <div ui-view></div>
   </div> 

   .state('setup.stepOne', {
      url: '/stepOne',
      controller: 'SetupStepOneCtrl',
      onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        $modal.open{
          backdrop: 'static',
          templateUrl: 'setup.stepOne.html',
          controller: 'SetupStepOneCtrl'
        })
      }   
   })  

   .state('setup.stepTwo', {
     url: '/stepTwo',
     controller: 'SetupStepTwoCtrl',
     onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
       $modal.open({
         backdrop: 'static',
         templateUrl: 'setup.stepTwo.html',
         controller: 'SetupStepTwoCtrl'
       })
     }   
    })  

    .state('setup.stepThree', {
      url: '/stepThree',
      templateUrl: 'setup.stepThree.html',
      controller: 'SetupStepThreeCtrl'
      ...
    }); 
}]);
```

I've also tried to only add the onEnter block to the abstract state, and removed onEnter from each of the 3 child states. This actually seems to me like the right approach. The abstract state initializes and opens the $modal and the subsequent states should interpolate into , but when I tried this the ui-view container was empty.

I can think of some other hacky ways to workaround this but thought I'd ask to see if there's a canonical way of handling this.

Comment: Hi, Im trying to do the same thing, did you solve this

Comment: same here, im having the same problem. any solutions?

Comment: no I never did get it to work, sorry.

Comment: I'm working on this very thing. So far I have the example from the FAQ working.

Comment: Hi, trying to do the same :). anyone has the solution and a sample code to look at? Thanks!!

Comment: +1, looking for a solution

Comment: Got it to work using `ngInclude`, `stateChangeStart`. Basically I dynamically inject templates on state change

Comment: I am sorry to ask but what does ui-router do that the regular router does not? I havent found any use for it yet. I am just using ng-includes.

Comment: @AlexC, personally I use it for the state system that allow me to change a path without having to refactor all the links in the UI.

Comment: did you tried using ng-route

Answer (score 5):

Alternative way is to use `ng-switch` with `ng-include` combination inside `$modal` controller to dynamically load wizard step templates, that is if you don't mind sharing the same controller for all wizard steps:

```
<div ng-switch="currentStep.number">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">
    <ng-include src="'wizardModalStep1.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">
    <ng-include src="'wizardModalStep2.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="3">
    <ng-include src="'wizardModalStep3.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here is Plunker with working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Og2U2fZSc3VECtPdnhS1?p=preview

Hope that helps someone !!

Answer (score 1):

I used following approach to develop a wizard. this might be help for you.

I used states like below sample with **parent** property.

```
 var home = {
            name: 'home',
            url: '/home',
            controller: 'MainController',
            templateUrl: '/html/main.html'
        },
        sampleWizard = {
            name: 'sampleWizard',
            url: '/sampleWizard',
            controller: 'sampleWizardController',
            templateUrl: '/html/sd/sample/sampleWizard.html'
        },
         sampleSectionOne = {
             name: 'sampleSectionOne',
             url: '/sampleSectionOne',
             parent: sampleWizard,
            controller: 'sampleSectionOneController',
            templateUrl: '/html/sd/sample/sampleSectionOne.html'
        },
        sampleSectionTwo = {
            name: 'sampleSectionTwo',
            url: '/sampleSectionTwo',
            parent: sampleWizard,
            controller: 'sampleSectionTwoController',
            templateUrl: '/html/sd/sample/sampleSectionTwo.html'
        };

        $stateProvider.state(home);
        $stateProvider.state(sampleWizard);
        $stateProvider.state(sampleSectionOne);
        $stateProvider.state(sampleSectionTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to fire the modal every single time you go to the next step.

I think all you have to do is create a modal view () then each step has a modal a templateUrl assigned to it.

each template should look like:

---

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="whatever" style="display:block">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a ui-sref="next_page_route_id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

---

On the last screen you can add a  data-dismiss="modal" to the submit and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with similar scenario, where I had to create a wizard (which allows you to go through steps and finally hit on summary and save).
For this, I had created different views but with one controller.
Since controller scope dies after each re-routing, I had  to save the scope of controller(Basically the model object associated with the wizard) in a service object for each routing in the wizard (Captured through location.path()) and load this object back from service object on load of controller.Something like below:-

```
// Saving data on routing
 $scope.nextPage = function () {
        service.ModelForWizard = $scope.ModelForWizard;
        switch ($location.path()) {
        case RouteOfPage1:
            //Do some stuff
            break;
        case RouteOfPage2:
           //Do some stuff
            break;

        default:
}
```

Service or factory is persisted throughout life time of user session and is ideal to hold user data.
One more thing which was helpful , was use of 'Resolve' in the routes.
It ensures that next page in not rendered until the required data(generally lookup data) is not loaded. Code of resolve is something like this:

```
.when('/RouteForWizardPage1', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/ViewPage1Wizard.html',
                caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
                controller: 'wizardController',
                resolve: {
                   wizardLookupDataPage1: function (Service) {
                        return service.getwizardModelLookupDataPage1().$promise;
                    }
                },
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same thing.. What worked for me was emptying the url property of the first sub state. Hence for the first sub state, your code should look as follows:

```
    .state('setup.stepOne', {
      url: '',
      controller: 'SetupStepOneCtrl',
      onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        $modal.open{
          backdrop: 'static',
          templateUrl: 'setup.stepOne.html',
          controller: 'SetupStepOneCtrl'
        })
      }   
   })
```

Also, incase you're not using the url property to call the other 3 sub states, and are calling them using the state name only, you don't necessarily need to mention a url property for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a wizard in a modal dialog and have a separate state for each of the wizard's steps, you need to keep in mind that the modal dialog is rendered completely outside your view hierarchy. Therefore, you cannot expect any interaction between `ui-router`'s view rendering mechanisms and the dialog contents.

A robust solution is to put the wizard contents manipulation logic onto the parent state scope

```
$scope.wizard = {
    scope: $scope.$new(),
    show: function (template) {
        // open the $modal if not open yet
        // purge scope using angular.copy()
        // return $scope.wizard.scope
    },
    // private
    open: function () {
        $modal.open({
            scope: $scope.wizard.scope,
            // ...
        });
    }
};
```

and then manually show the appropriate content from each of the sub-states and manipulate the wizard's scope as needed

```
$scope.wizard.show('someTemplate');
$scope.wizard.scope.user = ...;
```

---

When we faced this problem in our project, we decided after some discussion, that we didn't actually need separate `ui-router` states for the wizard steps. This allowed us to create a `wizard` directive used inside the dialog template to read wizard configuration from scope (using a format similar to `ui-router` state definition), provide methods to advance the wizard, and render appropriate view/controller inside the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To create multi-step wizards, you can use this module (I am the author): https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form.

It allows you to create steps like views, and you can enable navigation (back / forward button, url with an URL search parameter). Examples are available [here](http://blog.reactandbethankful.com/angular-multi-step-form).